# Build Apache Hadoop 2.5.1 in windows

Tags: windows, apache, hadoop, master-slave

I like to configure Hadoop Setup in windows environment is there any step to step guide available for installing Hadoop 2.5.1 in with configuring both hadoop master and slave in windows platform.

also like to know what are all the limitations in Hadoop windows Setup?

Answer (score 4):

Refer the below links to build Hadoop on windows :

1. http://harishshan.blogspot.in/2014/10/install-hadoop-251-on-windows-7-64bit.html
2. http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os